# Output a collection of messages at the end of running all the tests

Tags: mocha.js

We're using mocha. At the end of a test run, there is the following output.

```
  22 passing (1m)                    
  2 pending                          
  2 failing                          

  1) Some message and stack trace.

  2) Some message and stack trace.   

++++++++++++++
warn: Some condition happened.      <---- How do we do ths?
++++++++++++++
```

We want to add our own, custom message at the end there.

For instance, we have a condition in some tests like this:

```
it(..., () => {
  if(someConndition) {
    log("Some condition happened.");
  }
});
```

Our log function currently outputs to console, but we want to have it output **at the end of running all the tests.**

```
function log(message) {
  console.warn("++++++++++++++");
  console.warn(message);
  console.warn("++++++++++++++");
}
```